# Badge doesn't fit into bottom navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, badge

I tried using the Badge from https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui, but the element doesn't properly fit into the bottom navigation: 
[image]

Here's the code from AppNavigator.js:

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
import { Badge, Icon, Avatar } from "react-native-material-ui";

export const SignedIn = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    MeetingsScreen: {
      screen: MeetingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Заседания",
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <Badge text="3">
            <TabBarIcon
              focused={focused}
              name={
                Platform.OS === "ios"
                  ? `ios-people${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`
                  : "md-people"
              }
            />
          </Badge>
        )
      }
    },
...
```

I tried wrapping the TabBarIcon itself into the badge, but it didn't help.
How to set up this element properly? Or is there a better library for that?

Comment: Have you tried messing with `overflow` properties on the `TabBarIcon` or containing components?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom tab bar icon component that wraps the tab bar icon inside a view of greater width and height of the icon and make sure the badge is within the view perimeter. See diagram below:[image]